# Storing JQuery Xml Tree In Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

Xml:

```
<Data>
   <Cat>
      <Name>Fluffy</Name>
   </Cat>

   <Cat>
      <Name>Willy</Name>
   </Cat>
</Data>
```

JQuery:

```
// ...Some ajax calls...
$(xml).find('Cat').each(function() {
   var name = $(this).find('Name').text();
   alert(name);
});
```

How can I store the results of `find('Cat')` in a variable, so that I can pass it to a function and handle it there?  I thought something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
var cats = $(xml).find('Cat');
ShowCatNames(cats);
```

...

```
function ShowCatNames(cats) {
   $(cats).each(function() {
       var name = $(this).find('Name').text();
       alert(name);
   }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parsing the xml first

```
var cats = $($.parseXML(xml)).find('Cat');
```

Comment: Hi. I have specified in my AJAX call a `dataType` of `"xml"`.  However, I was only able to get your code to work if I specified the `dataType` as `"text"`.  I have read that specifying `xml` returns the same `XmlDocument` that you would get after calling `.parseXML`.  Do you know why this wouldn't work when I set my `dataType` as xml?
I was thinking that if I just set the `dataType` to xml, then I wouldn't have to call `.parseXML`

Comment: @Eric Try doing a console.log(xml) to see if you get an `XmlDocument`

Comment: Yes, actually, I just looked and it is an XmlDocument (it actually just says `Document`, but it is the same as when I call `.parseXML`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok, oddly enough, my original code is working now. I'll mark your answer, since it worked, as well. Thanks for the help.